Why is the Democracy Space Station unavailable?
If you go to the Galactic War table, you'll see that you can press B to go to the 'Democracy Space Station'.
However, every time I press B it says that

The Democracy Space Station is currently unavailable.

Why is this?

The Democracy Space Station has been overrun by Automatons.

The liberation campaign/sector (I'm not sure which is required) has been lost to the enemy, so the game won't let you go there.
Presumably, once the planet/sector (again, not sure which) is liberated, the Station will become available again.

It was sheer luck that I found this - I saw the weird symbol next to the planet and zoomed it, and that's when I saw the part about the Station.
